# Moya stub request in BDD tests

Tags: swift, moya, quick-nimble

I want to make a [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) stub request in my [Quick/Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) BDD tests. [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) has a `sampleData` parameter I created using a JSON file:

```
var sampleData: Data {
    switch self {
    case .getPlaces:
        // Provided that project have a file named get_places.json in it's bundle.
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "get_places", ofType: "json"),
            let data = Data(base64Encoded: path) else {
                return Data()
        }
        return data
    case .getPlaceDetail:
        // Provided that project have a file named get_place_detail.json in it's bundle.
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "get_place_detail", ofType: "json"),
            let data = Data(base64Encoded: path) else {
                return Data()
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

How can I use this parameter in tests? Any ideas to make a [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) stub request in tests?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use your provider like you did in your real code. Moya detects that current target is test target and will return the sample data instead of performing the request

Comment: I'm trying to write a test which checks a response from getPlaces request, but following both tests is successful for this response:

`testProvider.request(.getPlaces(location: "")) { places in
                    expect(places).to(beNil())
}`

and
`testProvider.request(.getPlaces(location: "")) { places in
                    expect(places).toNot(beNil())
                }`.
Why this happens? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create your test provider using stubClosure? Like this `let provider = RxMoyaProvider<YourTargetType>(stubClosure: MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're still interested to use sample data for development (if backend is not ready yet), you can create Moya provider passing `endpoint` closure like below:

```
let endpoint = { (target: NetworkApiService) -> Endpoint in
            return Endpoint(url: URL(target: target).absoluteString,
                            sampleResponseClosure: { .networkResponse(200, target.sampleData) },
                            method: target.method,
                            task: target.task,
                            httpHeaderFields: target.headers)
        }
let provider = MoyaProvider<NetworkApiService>(endpointClosure: endpoint, stubClosure: MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub)
```

It will return data, specified at `public var sampleData: Data` of `TargetType` protocol.